# Applied first order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a dose of $x_o$ (initial) gram of a drug is injected into the bloodstream. Assume that the drug leaves the blood and enters the urine at a rate proportional to the amount of drug present in the blood. In addition, assume that half of the drug dose has entered the urine after $0.75$ hour. Find the time at which the amount of drug in the blood stream is $5\%$ of the original drug dose $x_o$ (initial).

I have the first order differential equation. It's finding $t$ that is the problem.

Comment: tell us your differential equation, please

Comment: D = D0 (knot) * e^-kt

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the law is exponential decay and you get from $x(\frac34)=\frac12x_o$, $x(k\frac34)=\frac1{2^k}⋅x_o$ the formula
$$
x(t)=2^{-\frac43t}\cdot x_o
$$
where $t$ is measured in hours.

Now you have to solve
$$
2^{-\frac43t}=0.05\iff t=-\frac34\frac{\log 0.05}{\log 2}.
$$

Comment: How would you do this with natural logs?

Comment: I first used D = 50%, D0 = 100%, and t = 0.75h to solve for k, which is 0.92. Then I used D = 95%, D0 = 5%, and k = 0.92 to solve for t.

Comment: D = 5% and D0 = 100% for the second case. I can't seem to edit what I typed.

Comment: Of course you can set $\log=\ln$ and $2^y=e^{\ln(2)y}$. // Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes, copy and edit in new comment and delete the old one if it is important enough.